# Upload Using Youtube API

Tags: zend-framework, video, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a site where there's a search bar and a user inputs the URL of a youtube video and then press submit, and the youtube video gets uploaded to my site similar to how Facebook does it.

Does anyone know where to find a good tutorial on how this is possible using the Youtube API?

I'm also wondering if the Zend Framework Youtube API functionality makes this any easier

Comment: I think you need to bit more research and then reask your question. Start with https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started and http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to strip the video ID from the URL (probably using regex), store it in a database and then use that to embed the YouTube video on your page(s).  Using the Zend Framework is totally unnecessary.

Downloading the video file to your server isn't something you need to do and probably illegal, plus it's a lot more complicated and will cost you more in bandwidth than simply embedding YouTube's player.

These are the specific documentation pages which talk about embedding the player:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

If it's of interest, Facebook actually picks up the URI for a SWF player from the [Open Graph tags](http://ogp.me/#structured) in the YouTube page's header.  I wouldn't recommend doing this, since it limits your site's compatibility to browsers with Flash installed.